# How to apply my own function along each rows and columns with NumPy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm using NumPy to store data into matrices.
I'm struggling to make the below Python code perform better.
`RESULT` is the data store I want to put the data into.

```
TMP = np.array([[1,1,0],[0,0,1],[1,0,0],[0,1,1]])
n_row, n_col = TMP.shape[0], TMP.shape[0]
RESULT = np.zeros((n_row, n_col))

def do_something(array1, array2):
    intersect_num = np.bitwise_and(array1, array2).sum()
    union_num = np.bitwise_or(array1, array2).sum()
    try:
        return intersect_num / float(union_num)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return 0

for i in range(n_row):
    for j in range(n_col):
    if i >= j:
        continue
    RESULT[i, j] = do_something(TMP[i], TMP[j])
```

I guess it would be much faster if I could use some NumPy built-in function instead of for-loops.

I was looking for the various questions around here, but I couldn't find the best fit for my problem.
Any suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are looking for a generic solution, use the linked question. For a specific function, edit your question.

Comment: The `duplicate` was probably chosen because of its age and high score.  All it suggests is `np.vectorize`.  It ignores the fact that you are skipping the upper triangle. Try `for j in range(I,ncol)`.  For bettter help tell us more about the function.

Comment: `np.vectorize` is useful if you need help broadcasting; otherwise is syntactic sugar.  In this case it could be harmful.  It first tries to evaluate return type with a test calculation.  Also it provides values not indices.  So there's no way to test for upper or lower triangle

Comment: Also the function takes rows.  `vectorize` feeds scalars.  That is a **bad duplicate**.

Comment: Thanks, hpaulj. I edited the function.
Briefly, the function takes two arrays and return jaccard similarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1**

You could do something like this as a vectorized solution -

```
# Store number of rows in TMP as a paramter
N = TMP.shape[0]  

# Get the indices that would be used as row indices to select rows off TMP and 
# also as row,column indices for setting output array. These basically correspond
# to the iterators involved in the loopy implementation
R,C = np.triu_indices(N,1)    

# Calculate intersect_num, union_num and division results across all iterations
I = np.bitwise_and(TMP[R],TMP[C]).sum(-1)
U = np.bitwise_or(TMP[R],TMP[C]).sum(-1)
vals = np.true_divide(I,U)

# Setup output array and assign vals into it
out = np.zeros((N, N))
out[R,C] = vals
```

**Approach #2**

For cases with `TMP` holding `1s` and `0s`, those `np.bitwise_and` and `np.bitwise_or` would be replaceable with dot-products and as such could be faster alternatives. So, with those we would have an implementation like so -

```
M = TMP.shape[1]   
I = TMP.dot(TMP.T)
TMP_inv = 1-TMP
U = M - TMP_inv.dot(TMP_inv.T)
out = np.triu(np.true_divide(I,U),1)
```

Comment: @yukimilk Also, would `TMP` always have `1s` and `0s` only?

Comment: Yes. it only has 0 or 1 as type of np.int

Comment: @yukimilk Added another approach using dot-product, check it out too!

Comment: That is awesome. I really appreciate your big help, Divakar!